# Laravel do action after each chucking is complete?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Lets take the following example:

```
User::where('is_active', true)->each(function (User $user){
   // do something

}, 500);
```

So if I have 2000 users, is there a way to do something each time a new chunk of users ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User::where('is_active', true)->chunk(500, function (Collection $users) {
    $users->each(function (User $user) {
        // Do per-user stuff here
    });
    // Do per-chunk stuff here
}
```

This should do the trick. Keep in mind that the last chunk might contain less than 500 users. If it has to be exactly at every 500, check the collection size;

```
User::where('is_active', true)->chunk(500, function (Collection $users) {
    $users->each(function (User $user) {
        // Do per-user stuff here
    });
    if ($users->count() == 500) {
        // Do per-chunk stuff here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder did you test it? Because under the hood `each()` calls `chunk()`, so your code is like 'chunk() calls each() which calls chunk().

Comment: I did test it. It's correct that `each()` calls `chunk()`, but `chunk()` doesn't call `each()`. By calling `chunk()` directly, you get control of the callback argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `each()` helper, you need to make this manually. Do something like this:

```
$counter = 0;
$chunk = 500;

User::where('is_active', true)->each(function (User $user) use(&$counter, $chunk) {
    // Do stuff for each user.

    $counter += 1;
    if ($counter === $chunk) {
        $counter = 0;
        // Do something after each chunk.
        $this->doSomething();
    }
}, $chunk);

if (!$counter)
    // Do something for the last chunk.
    $this->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Not really I want to use the right one, that one is just one that I tried, if there is something that won't need `$counter` variables is better.

Comment: @jycr753 I've looked into the `each()` and `chunk()` source code and I don't see any better solution at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Yeah I did too, that is why I asked here... maybe just maybe some one knew a better/faster/smarter approach for it

Comment: @jycr753 you can try Rekondo's code. It looks like not working code to me, but the guy says he tested it. If you'll find a better solution please post it as answer, it'll be interesting to know about it. )

Comment: Sure thing will try a couple of possible solutions